# bdecode Library in Python doesn't work

Tags: python

I'm trying to decode a bencode format using the bdecode library in python. I have imported the bcode library as well in my python folder. When i try to use the function bdecode which is defined in the library. I get an error

```
                 File "C:\Python27\fit.py", line 21, in <module>
                 decoded = bdecode(data)
                 NameError: name 'bdecode' is not defined
```

Any idea why this error is happening, I'm just new to python? If this is because of the bcode library , could anyone submit a link to some other bcode library?

This is the code I'm trying

```
             import  bcode, urllib, urlparse, string
             url = "http://update.utorrent.com/installoffer.php?"
             url = url + "offer=conduit"

             filename = "out_py.txt"
             urllib.urlretrieve(url,filename)

             with open ("out_py.txt", "r") as myfile:
             data=myfile.readlines()

             decoded = bdecode(data)
```

Comment: Is that the whole .py file?  In particular what statement do you use to import the bdecode function?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this one of two ways, change your import statement:

```
from bcode import bdecode
import urllib, urlparse, string
```

Or change the line where you call the function:

```
decoded = bcode.bdecode(data)
```

The issue is that while you were importing the bcode module, you were not importing any of the  symbols within it in to the local namespace.

Comment: File "C:\Python27\fit.py", line 21, in <module>
    decoded = bcode.bdecode(data)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\bcode.py", line 155, in bdecode
    input = input.strip()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: File "C:\Python27\fit.py", line 23, in <module>
    decoded = bcode.bdecode(data)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\bcode.py", line 167, in bdecode
    return _decode_dict(input)[0]
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\bcode.py", line 33, in _decode_dict
    while remainder[0] != 'e':
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: it seems i have lot of errors in my bcode.py file , could any one suggest a link for a better library file?